# Does 'wasting' ammution reduces weight?

Tags: insurgency

In Insurgency (and sandstorm version), you can carry a Carrier which gives you more ammunition, and allows you to carry more grenades.

What I want is to carry more grenades, however equipping Carrier increases a lot of weight on my character, causing him to run slower than usual.

Question is, can I spam/waste ammunition at the start/spawn in order to reduce the weight on my character?